# Render a value in visualforce from a wrapper

Tags: visualforce, rendered

MyDetail is a class of which MyContacts is a wrapper where value is binded for UI.
MyDetail.Mycontacts has all its values as null in it. Here's with an example. My values-->`{!MyDetail.Mycontacts}` in visualforce gives me as:

```
 My values-->[someValue:[value1=null, value2=null, value3=null, value4=null]]
```

I want to render a table below if all the value are null then the table shouldn't show on VF. I have tried as following but doesn't seem to work.

```
<apex:pageblocktable value="{!MyDetail.Mycontacts}" border="1" rendered="{!MyDetail.Mycontacts}">
```

Any suggestion would be helpful. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you didn't handle the null condition of every attributes for rendering then how come it is expected to work?

Comment: As I said MyDetail.Mycontacts values are null. Shouldn't rendered attribute be working if values are null? That's my expectation.

Comment: rendered expression needs to resolve to boolean. Have you tried rendered="{!MyDetail.Mycontacts} <> null"?

Comment: Hi @DanielHoechst I added your suggestion, it does hide the table, but it also hide for those which has values too. So I tried  rendered="{!MyDetail.Mycontacts}!=null". Didn't work. Let me know if I can refer any doc

Comment: Hi @DanielHoechst. Thanks. I added your suggestion, it does hide the table, but it also hide for those which has values too. So I tried  rendered="{!MyDetail.Mycontacts}!=null". Didn't work. Let me know if I can refer any doc

Comment: Can you add your apex code here, probably you need to create a list which will have All null values and try to show the list in the VFP pageblockTable, otherwise it will not work

Comment: I tried yours and finally this worked--> (MyDetail.Mycontacts[0].value1!= '', it worked. Thanks!